# Simple blackjack javascript code

Tags: javascript

I wish to make a simple blackjack game with JavaScript. I started where it prints out `{ rank: '7', suit: '♥' }` (in a JSON format), but I would want it to print `7♥` into a string.

Any ideas how to get that to work? I also wish to get the game to work so that I can play it actively and it responds. Can anyone give me some advice on how to get it to do this?

```
function Card (rank, suit) {
    this.rank = rank;
    this.suit = suit;
}

function Deck () {
    this.deck = new Array();
    this.makeDeck = makeDeck;
    this.shuffle = shuffle;
    this.deal = deal;
}

function makeDeck() {
    var ranks = new Array("A","2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"),
        suits = new Array("♥", "♦", "♣", "♠"),
        deck = new Array(52);

    var i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i += 1) {
        for (j = 0; j < 13; k += 1) {
            this.deck[i * ranks.length + j] = new Card(ranks[j], suits[i]);
        }
    }
}

function shuffle() {
    var i, j, temp, n = 10;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i += 1) {
        for (j = 0; j < this.deck.length; j += 1) {
            k = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.deck.length);
            temp = this.deck[j];
            this.deck[j] = this.deck[k];
            this.deck[k] = temp;
        }
    }
}

function deal() {
    if (this.deck.length > 0) {
        return this.deck.shift();
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    var deck = new Deck();
    deck.makeDeck();
    deck.shuffle();

    var i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i += 1) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j += 1) {
            var Card = deck.deal();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: "Does anyone have any idea?"  About what?  You forgot to tell us what you're having trouble with.

Comment: Sorry! Have edited and I hope it's a bit more clear now. How to be able to play the game and also to be able to just print of 7 of hearts as the example.

Answer (score 0):

well You need to parse the JSON { rank: '7', suit: '♥' } to get the required output 7♥
just write like this 
`var jsonOutput =  { rank: '7', suit: '♥' } 
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonOutput)`

now print `obj.rank+ obj.suit`,answer will be 7♥.